# How to display the number of images contained in a node using Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type that has an image field (among other fields).
When creating a node, users can upload up to five files.
What i'm trying to do is to display how many images are uploaded in each node when listing node teasers using views ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the module: [Field Count Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_count_formatter)

> A very simple module to provide a formatter for all field types. The
>   output is simply a count of the number of items in that field. This is
>   most useful on fields which have multiple values as it will show how
>   many values are in this field.

Then in the teaser display for your content type, add the image field and set the formatter to count.

Comment: Ok, thanks i didn't know that module. Do you know if there's a way to achieve this without an additional module ?